# Crash when trying to run variable with optional

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, option-type

Hey im getting a crash when I run this code. I know exactly why, but I don't  know how to make it not crash.

Code:

```
// Is Global
weak var modelImage: UIImageView!

// this gets called in a function 

modelImage = UIImageView()
modelImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: modelSectionInfoCase.frame.width * 0.2, y: modelSectionInfoCase.frame.height * 0.1), size: CGSize(width: modelSectionInfoCase.frame.width / 5, height: modelSectionInfoCase.frame.height / 1.25))
modelImage.alpha = 1.0
modelImage.clipsToBounds = false
modelImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
modelImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
modelImage.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
modelSectionInfoCase.insertSubview(modelImage, at: 0)
modelSectionInfoCase.bringSubview(toFront: modelImage)
```

[image]

UPDATE:

I need to keep “weak var”, because I’m having a memory Issue. Memory Leak that I’m trying to fix with “weak var”. Not only on this variable but other variables as well with the same logic.

Comment: If you're using global variables like that I'm not surprised that you have a memory issue, but it's not being caused by this variable in particular. Just do what Khan said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply as warning says remove `weak`

```
var modelImage: UIImageView!
```

[image]

As you declare the imageView property as `weak` it won't hold any reference assigned to it , so it will keep it's value nil resulting in the crash , so leave it with it's default strong value

Comment: To add to this: The reason you can use `weak` with `@IBOutlets` is because Storyboards/XIBs hold strong references to their objects, which keep your references alive, even if they're `weak`

Comment: @Alexander, it's a little bit different. Read the doc [`addSubview(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview). _**This method establishes a strong reference to view**_ It's not Storyboards/XIB which keeps strong reference, but `UIView` keeps strong reference to its subviews.

Comment: @OOPer Ah. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a local variable which keeps strong reference till settings up are finished.

```
// this gets called in a function 

let modelImage = UIImageView()
modelImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: modelSectionInfoCase.frame.width * 0.2, y: modelSectionInfoCase.frame.height * 0.1), size: CGSize(width: modelSectionInfoCase.frame.width / 5, height: modelSectionInfoCase.frame.height / 1.25))
modelImage.alpha = 1.0
modelImage.clipsToBounds = false
modelImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
modelImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
modelImage.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
modelSectionInfoCase.insertSubview(modelImage, at: 0)
modelSectionInfoCase.bringSubview(toFront: modelImage)

self.modelImage = modelImage
```

---

(ADDITION)

As I noted in my comments, `UIView` keeps strong reference to its subviews, so my code works.

But that does not mean you cannot hold another strong reference to any of subviews. If you have no reason to make your property `weak`, it may be safe to make it strong as in Sh_Khan's answer.

Comment: This fixes the crash, but leads to what is probably undesirable behavior, as the image will be almost instantly deinitialized.

Comment: @Alexander, think carefully what happens with my code.

Comment: Ahhh, I missed that "insertSubview(_:at:)" call.

Comment: @Alexander, thanks for finding out so fast. And I think I should have noted about strong reference about view hierarchy as many readers would not know much about that. Thanks again, for a nice suggestion.

Comment: Ok looks good but, I need the variable to have “weak var”. Like I need to keep the declaration “weak var modelImage: UIImageView”

Comment: @Hunter, then you need something like my answer. You should better have noted it in your question.

Comment: @Hunter, one more, I hope that you know usual usage of local variables does not make reference cycle, my code fits for your purpose.

Comment: The variable is declared as a Global. I should have stated that better, I apologize

Comment: @Hunter, You can declare the Global variable as `weak`. And my local `let modelImage` is a local variable _called in a function_, so it does not make reference cycle, ok?

Comment: Can you re-write your answer. I only ask this because I can’t apply this method to my Global variables with “weak”, If it’s possible.

Comment: @Hunter, sorry to be so late, I was on my job. By the way I thought your Global meant just _non-local_ and was an instance property. If it really is a global variable, generally, global variables are not kept in any instances, so `weak` globals does not help solving reference cycles. Do you still want me to re-write my answer?

Comment: no Its ok it seems my memory issue can't be solved this way